# PHP Warning Error in ftp_put()

Tags: php, shell, ftp, server

Hi I using a script to upload lot of files to server and it worked fine untill before twodays. But now it works for sometime and staring to fail if i restart it continues. And here i added the screenshot appreiciate any help thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5nA4.jpg)

Comment: Post code and error messages in the question. Don't use pictures.

Answer (score -1):

Check if destination location exists or you had an typing mistake.

Comment: code is fine and there is no typing mistake and destination path also correct